# The Apple ID "example@email.com" cannot be used to unlock this iPhone

Tags: iphone, apple-id

Recently I bought a second hand iPhone 8. When I'm trying to unlock the device It shows this error:
`The Apple ID "example@email.com" cannot be used to unlock this iPhone`

- Previous user deleted this device from "find my iPhone" service (But still it shows "Erase requested 1hour ago")

How can I register my device under my apple ID? 
Do they take more time to erase a device from the database ?

Comment: Is the iPhone connected to a WiFi or a cellular network? Without a network connection the request from "Find my iPhone" can not reach your phone.

Comment: @nohillside Yes. It is connected.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because given the OPs answer this is the issue that the previous owner had not deactivated the phone - the original owner and the new owner now both have access so not a good idea for future viewers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked previous owner to enter his Apple ID and Password. After that it gave me a pop up window to add my Apple ID. Now It works correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Apple’s activation servers are generally instant. I’ve gone through the official process maybe 20 times in the past two years for work, and it has never not worked within 1 minutes let alone waiting 5.

Here is the official guide and link for the previous user to remove that lock:

- https://support.apple.com/HT201365

Activation Lock is part of the iOS Activation status here:

- https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/

So if you believe it’s failing, the instructions there are correct - contact Apple Support directly. The only thing I can add, is Apple doesn’t tell you the full email of the previous owner, so unless you have the passcode, you won’t really know which email is “example@email.com” above.

- How exactly are you connected to the internet from the device to try and unlock / activate it?
- Do you actually know the email some other way or were you putting something hypothetical in the question?